# mongodb get first element after find query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, express, find

I can't find the answer. I have a query that can return many answer and I want to get the last one. How to do it?

```
db.users.find({username: "bob", sort: {createdAt: -1}}).first()
```

I would like something like this.

Answer (score 0):

do this to get last N records :

```
function last(N) {
    return db.collection.find().skip(db.collection.count() - N);
}
```